# searching by extensions in specific folder winapi32

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to create a search directory , but at the same time . I want to search specific files such as `.txt ,and .jpg` over multiples directories , but how can I achieve this ? this is what I got so far

```
int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[])
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
    LARGE_INTEGER filesize;
    TCHAR szDir[MAX_PATH];
    size_t length_of_arg;
    HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    DWORD dwError = 0;


    StringCchCopy(szDir, MAX_PATH, L"C:\\Users\\USER-U\\Documents\\aaa\\project1\\Release\\");
    StringCchCat(szDir, MAX_PATH, TEXT("\\*"));

    // Find the first file in the directory.

    hFind = FindFirstFile(szDir, &ffd);

    // List all the files in the directory with some info about them.

    do
    {
        if (ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        {
            _tprintf(TEXT("  %s   <DIR>\n"), ffd.cFileName);
        }
        else
        {
            filesize.LowPart = ffd.nFileSizeLow;
            filesize.HighPart = ffd.nFileSizeHigh;
            _tprintf(TEXT("  %s   %ld bytes\n"), ffd.cFileName, filesize.QuadPart);
        }
    } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);

    dwError = GetLastError();


    FindClose(hFind);
    return dwError;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to search with different file type at the time or retrieve subdirectories?

Comment: Since you know how to get the list of files in a directory, it shouldn't be difficult to adapt it to get the list of files in two directories. And to do some filtering on the file name. (The code you "got so far" appears to simply have been copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56363831).)

Comment: yea , but for example if I want to implement more thn 400 extensions . it cannot use 400 `IF`

Comment: Yes you could. Also, there are ways to avoid large if-else-statements, for example use a lookup/hash-tables instead. That doesn't change anything about the general advice though (you need to filter for those extensions yourself).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to search for multiple file types, it is not supported, but you can use `*.*` and filter the result.
If you want to retrieve subdirectories, you can use a recursive function to retrieve (if the current search is a directory), and I will update the example later.

UPDATE:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>
#pragma warning (disable: 4996)
void retrievetxt(TCHAR* szDir)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
    LARGE_INTEGER filesize;
    _tcscat(szDir, _T("\\*"));
    HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile(szDir, &ffd);

    // List all the files in the directory with some info about them.

    do
    {
        if (ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        {

            if (!_tcscmp(ffd.cFileName, _T(".")) || !_tcscmp(ffd.cFileName, _T("..")))
                continue;
            TCHAR szDircpy[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
            _tcscpy(szDircpy, szDir);
            szDircpy[_tcslen(szDircpy)-1] = _T('\0'); // remove "*" character from "xxx\\*"
            _tcscat(szDircpy, ffd.cFileName); //add the subdirectory name into szDir
            _tprintf(TEXT("Go into  %s\\%s   <DIR>\n"), szDircpy, ffd.cFileName);
            retrievetxt(szDircpy);
        }
        else
        {
            int size = _tcslen(ffd.cFileName);
            if (size > 4 && !_tcscmp(ffd.cFileName + size - _tcslen(_T(".txt")), _T(".txt")))
            {
                filesize.LowPart = ffd.nFileSizeLow;
                filesize.HighPart = ffd.nFileSizeHigh;
                _tprintf(TEXT("%s   %ld bytes\n"), ffd.cFileName, filesize.QuadPart);
            }
        }
    } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);
    FindClose(hFind);
}
int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[])
{

    TCHAR szDir[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    _tcscpy(szDir,_T("C:\\Users\\drakew\\Desktop\\Newfolder"));
    _tprintf(TEXT("Go into  %s   <DIR>\n"), szDir);
    retrievetxt(szDir);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search with multiple extensions, you can use [ISearchFolderItemFactory interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-isearchfolderitemfactory)

For example, a test by searching *.jpg or *.png in a directory "e:\test" =>

(reference : [ExplorerBrowserSearch](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Win7Samples/winui/shell/appplatform/ExplorerBrowserSearch) SDK sample)

```
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
ISearchFolderItemFactory* pSearchFolderItemFactory = NULL;
hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(SearchFolderItemFactory), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pSearchFolderItemFactory));
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    WCHAR wsFolder[MAX_PATH] = L"e:\\test";
    IShellItem *pShellItem = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = SHCreateItemFromParsingName(wsFolder, NULL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pShellItem));
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        IShellItemArray* pShellItemArray = NULL;
        hr = SHCreateShellItemArrayFromShellItem(pShellItem, IID_IShellItemArray, (void**)&pShellItemArray);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = pSearchFolderItemFactory->SetScope(pShellItemArray);
            IQueryParserManager *pQueryParserManager = NULL;
            HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(QueryParserManager), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pQueryParserManager));
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                IQueryParser *pQueryParser = NULL;
                hr = pQueryParserManager->CreateLoadedParser(L"SystemIndex", LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pQueryParser));
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    IQuerySolution* pQuerySolution = NULL;
                    hr = pQueryParser->Parse(L"*.jpg OR *.png", NULL, &pQuerySolution);
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    {
                        ICondition* pCondition = NULL;
                        hr = pQuerySolution->GetQuery(&pCondition, NULL);
                        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                        {
                            SYSTEMTIME st;
                            GetLocalTime(&st);
                            ICondition* pConditionResult = NULL;
                            hr = pQuerySolution->Resolve(pCondition, SQRO_DONT_SPLIT_WORDS, &st, &pConditionResult);
                            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                            {
                                hr = pSearchFolderItemFactory->SetCondition(pConditionResult);
                                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                                {
                                    IShellItem* pShellItem = NULL;
                                    hr = pSearchFolderItemFactory->GetShellItem(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pShellItem));
                                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                                    {
                                        IEnumShellItems *pEnumShellItems = NULL;
                                        hr = pShellItem->BindToHandler(NULL, BHID_EnumItems, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pEnumShellItems));
                                        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                                        {
                                            IShellItem *psi;
                                            PWSTR pszName = NULL;
                                            while (S_OK == pEnumShellItems->Next(1, &psi, NULL))
                                            {                                                           
                                                hr = psi->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, &pszName);
                                                WCHAR wsBuffer[MAX_PATH];
                                                wsprintf(wsBuffer, L"File : %s\n", pszName);
                                                OutputDebugString(wsBuffer);
                                                psi->Release();
                                            }
                                            pEnumShellItems->Release();
                                        }
                                        pShellItem->Release();
                                    }                                               
                                }
                                pConditionResult->Release();
                            }
                            pCondition->Release();
                        }
                        pQuerySolution->Release();
                    }
                    pQueryParser->Release();
                }
                pQueryParserManager->Release();
            }
            pShellItemArray->Release();
        }
        pShellItem->Release();
    }
    pSearchFolderItemFactory->Release();
}
```

Comment: Wow, 11 levels of nested `if` statements. `CComPtr` to the rescue!

Comment: Yes :-) But I always copy-paste parts of my old code (90's...) to make samples and I'm too lazy to rewrite error handlers with CComPtr